# Same user on each iteration checkbox in Jmeter should be selected or deselected for performance testing?

Tags: jmeter

Same user on each iteration checkbox : If this check box is checked, then the session/cookie will be same throughout the execution.

Same user on each iteration checkbox : If this check box is unchecked, then you should get a new session/cookie every time

This all i understand, but i do not get which is useful from this both and which one not for the performance testing?

Answer (score 1):

If you tick the box on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you will be able to use it in conjunction with the following test elements:

1. [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

   [image]
2. [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) (it will control whether the user will be downloading [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) on the next iteration or not)

   [image]

The setting was introduced for your convenience so you would be able to choose between "new" and "returning" users in one place. Whether you want "new" or "returning" users depends on what type of test you're running and what you're trying to achieve. The only golden rule there is that your test needs to be **realistic**